# Sitecore debug task scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I conifgured the sitecore task scheduler to auto publish the site, and I want to debug it on my local machine. I attached to w3wp.exe process, but isn't hitting. What process should I be attaching to? Is it not running in the same thread? THere is only one website on my machine, and no other app pool running...

Comment: It might be easier to create a simple page you can hit that calls your scheduled task directly?  Just a thought.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What part of your code do you wan to debug?
Attaching to the W3WP process is correct.

Comment: It definitely should be w3wp.exe process. Are you sure that the scheduler is setup properly and the task is executed at all? Is there any information in the logs about the job being executed?

Answer (score 2):

As patrickmjones commented, a simple page is enough to test this. As long as its sitting under the website folder, you don't even need to have a Sitecore item for the page and it will still have a valid Sitecore context.

Create an aspx page with a runat server script block (no need for a code-behind) where you create an instance of your scheduled task class and call it's 'Run' method.

Answer (score 0):

By default with Visual Studio you cannot attach the debugger to Sitecore's `Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent` since its compiled into the Sitecore assembly. You can still do this with additional software:

You can use a disassembler that works with Visual Studio, such as [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) ($95) to decompile the assembly and generate the necessary ***.pdb** file to debug it. You can then attach the debugger to `Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent`'s `Run()` method to see what happens.